# Javadoc for a method with annotated arguments

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gradle, java-8, javadoc

I'd like to write a Javadoc comment for a method like this:

```
@GetMapping("/{foo}/{bar}/{baz}")
public String aMethod(
    @PathVariable("foo") String foo,
    @PathVariable("foo") String bar,
    @PathVariable("foo") String baz
){
  // the body of the method
}
```

The problem is that the method signature in the detailed method description gets corrupt: there is a gigantic offset (spaces) before annotated arguments, so that one should horizontally scroll to actually see them. Ugly.

I'm using Java 8, Eclipse Oxygen on Windows 7. The Javadocs are built with Gradle 4.8.1. Not sure if any of this is relevant, but posting the details shouldn't hurt.

Is it possible to remedy the problem? If it is, how?

Comment: is there a possibility to have it as requestParam ?

Comment: @Hrudayanath: quite certainly. It doesn't even have to use Spring or even Java for that matter. But, as a matter of principle, I'm not changing my code to please a misbehaving text parser. My question is about handling annoted arguments by javadoc.